# How can I detect which iBeacon is getting out of the range?

Tags: ios, xcode, cllocationmanager, ibeacon

I am using CLLocationManager to detect iBeacons in my iOS app.

I need to use below method to detect if my device is getting out of a region of a beacon.

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion   *)region
```

How can I detect of which iBeacon's region my device is getting out of range out of three iBeacons I am using?

I tried below code but I am not getting values of Major and Minor.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager didEnterRegion: (CLRegion *)region
{
  CLBeaconRegion *beaconRegion = (CLBeaconRegion*) region;
  NSLog(@"%@",beaconRegion.major);
  NSLog(@"%@",beaconRegion.minor);
  NSLog(@"%@",beaconRegion.proximityUUID);

  NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Major:%@ Minor:%@",beaconRegion.major,beaconRegion.minor];
  UILocalNotification *notification = [UILocalNotification new];
  notification.alertBody = str;
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the value of RSSI which gives the value of signal strength of the currently connected beacon. Upto a point the signal strength with continue to drop and if there is another beacon available within range it's possible that the device gets connected to other beacon.

In summary you can check the signal strength using RSSI value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons
           inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region {

    if (beacons.count) {
        CLBeacon * beacon = beacons[2]; // If you want to detect the range of third beacon 

        switch (beacon.proximity) {

            case CLProximityUnknown:
                NSLog(@"Unknown");
                break;
            case CLProximityFar:
                NSLog(@"Far");
                break;
            case CLProximityNear:
                NSLog(@"Near");
                break;
            case CLProximityImmediate:
                NSLog(@"Immediate");
            default:
                NSLog(@"No beacons found");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

If it came inside CLProximityUnknown you get to know that beacon is getting out of range

Answer (score 0):

Using CoreLovation monitoring APIs you cannot tell when individual beacons in a monitored `CLBeaconRegion` go out of range.  You only get one callback to `didExit` when *all* beacons have exited the region.  You cannot read the major and minor fields of individual beacons -- you only get access to the region object you used to set up mo itoring, and these were probably nil in your case.

Two common ways around this:

- **Define multiple `CLBeaconRegion`s to each only match a single beacon.** (Populate the major and minor.) The main limitation is that you may only monitor 20 regions at a time.
- **Use ranging APIs.**  You can call `[location?Manager startRangingBeacon sInRegion: region]` then you get a callback once per second with all the beacons detected in that interval, with all the identifiers populated.  I typically store these in a `NSDictionary` keyed by beacon identifiers and holding a `NSDate` of when the beacon was last detected.  Then I periodically look for any beacons not seen in the past 15 seconds and I know these have exited.

The disadvantage of the second approach is that you can only range when the app is in the foreground and for a few seconds after it moves to the background.